# android:fontFamily requires api level 16, but docs say level 15 is ok?

Tags: android

How do I set the font family on API level 15? The docs say API 15 *does* have the fontFamily attribute. I hoped the docs would say

> "This is depcrecated in API level 15. For API level 15 and lower, see [........]"

but they don't. How do I set the font in XML (or programmatically) without generating this warning?

This is a screenshot from Android Studio on Ubuntu.

styles.xml:

[image]

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are wrong what you are seeing is the `class API` not the `attribute` API level:

You can [look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fontFamily) and said:

```
public static final int fontFamily
Added in API level 16
```

Font families are actually create since [android 4.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html) not in `4.0.3-4.0.4`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I set the font family on API level 15, now that I am convinced I can't use android:fontFamily?

Comment: @RockLee in style not that I know of, porgramatically yes using TypeFace.

Comment: I think you mean the setTypeface method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29 Just making it clear for future visitors of this page.

Comment: @RockLee yes programatically and xml.

Comment: oh, ok. Found the xml version here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#typeface

Comment: @RockLee so using `android:typeface` solve the issue for custom font? the alternative for using `fontFamily` but support API level 15

Comment: @mochadwi I don't remember because this question is 6 years old, but if that doesn't work, then `setTypeface(typeface)` method should work on API 15.