# Hindi unicode text incorrect on Android 4.1

Tags: android, unicode, hindi

I have a piece of Hindi text:

> हाइड्रोजन परआॅक्साइड 3%

([Image of the text in case the quote is rendered incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GQRY.png))

On [Android API 16 a character is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ8Qu.png) and a dotted circle is shown instead. This is **regardless of the font used**. On Android API 26 the text is [rendered correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMyXC.png). This makes me wonder if there's something wrong with the original text or if Android's Unicode handling is at fault.

I don't speak Hindi myself so this is hard for me to reason about.

Comment: Well i do not know hindi too but i would not say 'an error occurs' but 'all is displayed well except for one character'. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @greenapps, Right, that's a more precise description of the issue. I've changed the question.

Comment: And after that i would have made clear which character exactly.

Comment: which font are you using? We have an app which supports Hindi locale. We use [Noto Sans Devanagari](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-deva).
Can you try this font and check if it solves the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16108088/4407266

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25456932/4407266